# Автомобиль "Нива" — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой буквы пишется слово "Нива", когда обозначает не марку машины, а конкретный автомобиль? С прописной, как "Волга"? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычками выделяются названия типа:
**·** автомобили «Волга», «Жигули», «Чайка», «форд», «кадиллак», «вольво»...
Примечание. Не выделяются кавычками наименования марок машин и производственных изделий, ставшие общеупотребительными названиями, например: наган, браунинг, мерседес, панасоник (если они употребляются без родового названия).
[§131. Названия фабричных марок машин, производственных изделий и т.д.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/54.htm) (Розенталь)

"Нива" в обычном тексте должна быть написана в кавычках и с прописной (как имя собственное).

*Никита и Юля молча смотрели, как «Нива», круто развернувшись, направилась в сторону Миролюбов*а (И. Мельникова, Г. Ланской); *Он залез на заднее сиденье и, когда «Нива» тронулась с места и набрала ход, перегруженный впечатлениями последних дней, неожиданно смежил веки и задремал* (А. Троицкий).

Answer (score 1):

Да, название автомобиля  "Нива" **пишется с прописной буквы,** это имя собственное.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=28#pp28

5. Индивидуальные названия марок машин заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы: автомобили «Руссо-Балт», «Рено-8», «Ситроен-100», «Фольксваген-600»; комбайн «Дон-600».
   Серийные названия автомобилей, выраженные словами, заключаются в кавычки и пишутся со строчной буквы: «победа», «запорожец», «пежо», «роллс-ройс», «ситроен», «фиат», «вольво» «фольксваген», **но: «Волга», «Таврия» и т. п. (названия — имена собственные).**

Пример:

На одном участке упавшая сосна разрушила сарай, на другом ― пробила **автомобиль «Нива».** [Людмила Пирогова. Для вырубки деревьев должно быть основание (2003) // «Встреча» (Дубна), 2003.03.10]